Alternative to using a tikzpicture inside of a tikzmarknode
I am trying to put a math equation with a custom \mathparallelogram inside of a \tikzmarknode. I tried some stuff, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Is this because the tikzpictures are nested? If that is the case, how could
I make \mathparallelogram tikz-compatible?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\mathparallelogram}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw 
            (0,0) -- 
            ++(65:4pt) -- 
            ++(6pt,0) -- 
            ++(65:-4pt) -- 
            cycle;
        \path 
            (current bounding box.south west) 
            +(-1pt,-1pt) 
            (current bounding box.north east) 
            +(1pt,1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmarknode{abc}{{A}_{\mathparallelogram}=B}
\]
\end{document}

Log
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.3.29)  22 DEC 2024 03:56
 system commands enabled.
**name.tex
(./name.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-resolved path "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count194
\c@pgf@countb=\count195
\c@pgf@countc=\count196
\c@pgf@countd=\count197
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count198
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count199
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count266
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count267
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count268
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count269
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count270
\pgf@shadingcount=\count271
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count272
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count273
\tikznumberofchildren=\count274
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count275
\tikz@fig@count=\count276
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count277
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count278
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count279
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count280
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzmark/tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex 2022/08/24 v1.15 TikZ library for marking positions in a document
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count281
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2024-03-14 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
\l__sn_x_dim=\dimen192
\l__sn_y_dim=\dimen193
\l__sn_xa_dim=\dimen194
\l__sn_ya_dim=\dimen195
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = output.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 19.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count282
\scratchdimen=\dimen196
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count283
\nofMParguments=\count284
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count285
\MPscratchDim=\dimen197
\MPnumerator=\count286
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count287
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 20.

! Package pgf Error: No shape named `abc-d' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \tikzmarknode{abc}{{A}_{\mathparallelogram}=B}
                                                 

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 12239 strings out of 476435
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 823 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 1 rule, 1 local_par, 10 dir, 13 glue, 3 kern, 1 penalty, 1 style, 1 choice, 1 noad, 2 math_char, 1 glyph, 36 attribute, 52 glue_spec, 36 attribute_list, 9 temp, 4 if_stack, 4 write, 1 save_pos, 17 pdf_literal, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:3,3:1,5:2,8:1
 34025 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 25 fonts using 1345055 bytes
 102i,9n,101p,409b,925s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


what's the intended result?

Hello @cfr, the intended result is to highlight a formula with this symbol in it. I have made several such symbols. that could potentially be highlighted.

have you checked whether the symbols are available in fonts already? that usually gives better results more straightforwardly.

@cfr see my comment to your answer. In short, I made it because the already available ones were hard for me to recognize

It's not obvious what the goal is here. There are easier ways to produce geometric symbols, for example, so presumably this is only an example. If so, one easy way to avoid the nesting problem is just to save the inner picture. If you plan to use it more than once, this will pay dividends in terms of efficiency, too, since you wan't be repeatedly invoking tikz (slow), but merely reusing a simply box (fast).

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\mathparallelogram}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
    (0,0) --
    ++(65:4pt) --
    ++(6pt,0) --
    ++(65:-4pt) --
    cycle;
    \path
    (current bounding box.south west)
    +(-1pt,-1pt)
    (current bounding box.north east)
    +(1pt,1pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newsavebox\parallelbox
\sbox\parallelbox{%
  \mathparallelogram
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[
    \tikzmarknode{abc}{{A}_{\usebox\parallelbox}=B}
\]
\end{document}


What might some of those easier ways to produce geometric symbols be? I made this one in particular because the ones from the symbols list weren't well-defined enough

@Jasper well, I was thinking of fonts in the first instance. (I'm not sure what you mean by 'well-defined'?) but if nothing like that exists, picture mode is much lighter weight. failing that, tikz has a library of geometrical shapes available ready-made. maybe this really is the best approach, but it seems unlikely for symbols as relatively simple as this?

I found that the parallelogram in the fonts list looked like a rectangle. The goal is just to have a parallelogram and a half-parallelogram as shapes. I thought I'd just make them myself. Let me look at the premade geometrical shapes, and at the picture environment. [Note: not all symbols are as simple as this, for instance I have made smiley faces too]

@Jasper you should look at tikzsymbols which provides a framework for this, as well as some ready-made symbols. (smiley faces included, but not parallelograms, I don't think.) you could use that framework for your own symbols, which would probably help keep compilation times in check.

@Jasper Did you try \parallelogram from stix? It looks very similar to your shape.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I was initially using that symbol, but thought that it looked too much like a rectangle
